# Es posible usar Json Web Token sin instalar con composer

Tags: php, jwt

Muy buenas, me gustaría poder usar JWT sin instalarlo con composer, he visto que un compañero lo ha podido hacer llamado a las librerias con require_once, el caso es que cuando quiero usar

```
 $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

Me da un error la web. Este sería el codigo con las llamadas a las librerías

```
<?php //Este archivo lo que hara será pintar la tabla de la tarea por factura
    require_once('../jwt/BeforeValidException.php');
    require_once('../jwt/ExpiredException.php');
    require_once('../jwt/JWT.php');
    require_once('../jwt/SignatureInvalidException.php');

    $key = "example_key";
    $token = array(
       "iss" => "http://example.org",
       "aud" => "http://example.com",
       "iat" => 1356999524,
       "nbf" => 1357000000
    );

    $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
    $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
    ?>
```

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Cómo podrías usar **una librería externa** sin instalarla?

Comment: Buenas, las librerias las tengo descargadas, me preguntaba si las podia incluir con require_once. un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te enredes con  esa libreria de firebase/php-jwt, JWT es muuy sencillo mira:

```
            <?php


        // base64 encodes the header json
        $arr = array('alg' => 'HS256', 'typ' => 'JWT');
        $arr2 = json_encode($arr);
        $encoded_header = base64_encode($arr2);


        // base64 encodes the payload json
        $arr3 = array('country' => 'Venezuela', 'name' => 'Julio Gonzalez', 'email' => 'email@gmail.com');
        $arr33 = json_encode($arr3);
        $encoded_payload = base64_encode($arr33);

        // base64 strings are concatenated to one that looks like this
        $header_payload = $encoded_header . '.' . $encoded_payload;

        //Setting the secret key
        $secret_key = 'clave secreta';

        // Creating the signature, a hash with the s256 algorithm and the secret key. The signature is also base64 encoded.
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $header_payload, $secret_key, true));

        // Creating the JWT token by concatenating the signature with the header and payload, that looks like this:
        $jwt_token = $header_payload . '.' . $signature;

        //listing the resulted  JWT
        echo $jwt_token;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        echo "<br><hr>";

        //AQUI VERIFICAMOS LA FIRMA

        //Verifying the Signature

        $recievedJwt = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiVmVuZXp1ZWxhIiwibmFtZSI6Ikp1bGlvIEdvbnphbGV6IiwiZW1haWwiOiJlbWFpbEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ==.h3tBXSN978DPxKxgJh20mc2DaqSdWuYhKJ9O1iBV6Pk=';

        $secret_key = 'clave secreta';

        // Split a string by '.' 
        $jwt_values = explode('.', $recievedJwt);

        // extracting the signature from the original JWT 
        $recieved_signature = $jwt_values[2];

        // concatenating the first two arguments of the $jwt_values array, representing the header and the payload
        $recievedHeaderAndPayload = $jwt_values[0] . '.' . $jwt_values[1];

        // creating the Base 64 encoded new signature generated by applying the HMAC method to the concatenated header and payload values
        $resultedsignature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $recievedHeaderAndPayload, $secret_key, true));

        // checking if the created signature is equal to the received signature
        if($resultedsignature == $recieved_signature) {

            // If everything worked fine, if the signature is ok and the payload was not modified you should get a success message
            echo "Success";
        } else {

            echo "Password no valida";

        }

        ?>
```

Aqui tienes ua explicacion completa y muy muy sencilla ==> http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/security/using-a-json-web-token-in-php.html

Comment: La respuesta no está mal... pero es una mala práctica. Primero, los manejadores de dependencias existen para quitar de tu app todo lo que no sea tu propósito. Si ya hay una librería de JWT, no reinventes la rueda. Segundo, esas librerías proveen encapsulamiento. Meter lógica adicional no es gratis para cuando a otro (o a uno mismo) le toque mantener el código. De paso, a ese JWT le falta el rango de validez. Not Before y Not After